# Macro to toggle 'dark mode' page colour, some issues?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros, colors

I have tried to create a VBA macro to change the page colour and make it the same as the Microsoft Office-wide dark mode background.

My issue is that when I run the macro on a fresh document, it does not actually change the page colour at first. Going into **Design>Page Colour** shows me that the macro did indeed toggle the colour I want, but the page itself doesn't change accordingly. I have to press it manually for it to actually 'confirm'. Then, I can toggle/untoggle the colour through my macro without issues. Any ideas as to what is going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
Sub DarkMode()
'
' DarkMode Macro
If ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoFalse Then
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = _
    wdThemeColorText1
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0.15
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Solid
Else
ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to allow View to Display Backgrounds by adding `ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.DisplayBackgrounds = True` to the code.

The full code would become:

```
 Sub DarkModeNewPage()

 ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.View.DisplayBackgrounds = True
 If ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoFalse Then
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = _
       wdThemeColorText1
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0.15
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Solid
 Else
    ActiveDocument.Background.Fill.Visible = msoFalse
 End If


 End Sub
```